# How to create table with raw SQL in symfony controller and get a response

Tags: php, sql, symfony, controller, doctrine

I have a controller where I create a table with doctrine raw sql:

```
$sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testTable
(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id))
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB';
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$statement = $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
```

Yet I cannot seem to figure out how to get a response to know if it executed successfully. Any ideas?

Comment: If there is a problem then an exception will be thrown.  No exception means that the table was created.  In other words, no need to do or check anything. Though execute does return true on success.

Answer (score 2):

Cerad is correct. Get the `errorCode` and check if it is '0000'. I'm using MySQL and I get '0000' as an errorCode if it ran successfully.

```
...
$statement->execute();

var_dump( $statement->errorCode() );   // Get the error code.
```

I think that should work for you.

For reference I got that from the Doctrine API documentation and I tried it out. Here is the link for reference:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.4/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Driver.Statement.html

Answer (score 1):

Response should be in your "statement" variable, add a: `var_dump($statement);` and see.